# onClick event only triggers once when on a form element

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm attempting to create a form which toggles accessability features however the onClick event only works once and I'm unsure as to why. Here's my code:

```js
function updateAccessible() {
  if (document.getElementById("font").value === true) {
    console.log("update true")
    document.querySelector(':root').style.setProperty('--font', 'cursive, sans-serif')
  } else {
    console.log("update false")
    document.querySelector(':root').style.setProperty('--font', 'sans-serif')
  }

  document.getElementById("accessibleForm").addEventListener("click", updateAccessible)
}
```

```css
:root {
  --font: cursive, sans-serif;
}

* {
  font-family: var(--font)
}
```

```html
<form onclick="updateAccessible()" id="accesibleForm">
  <input type="checkbox" name="font" id="font" checked><label for="font">Use custom font</label>
</form>

<p>Example Text</p>
```

Comment: The [*HTMLInputElement value property*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#instance_properties) is always a string, so `document.getElementById("font").value === true` will always be false.

Comment: EVERY TIME you click you add a new event listener! Why??

Comment: accesibleForm !== accessibleForm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this that way:

- `<input type="checkbox"` have a `checked` **property** with a direct boolean value
- prefer to use `names` of form elements childs to access any of them
- use only one `.addEventListener()` method
- prefer to use `change` event for a `checkbox`

```js
const
  Root          = document.querySelector(':root')
, accesibleForm = document.querySelector('#accesibleForm')
  ;
  
//            fontChkBx is the element name  
accesibleForm.fontChkBx.addEventListener('change', (e) =>
  {
  if (accesibleForm.fontChkBx.checked)
    Root.style.setProperty('--font', 'cursive, sans-serif');
  else
    Root.style.setProperty('--font', 'sans-serif');
    
  console.clear();
  console.log('update --> ' + accesibleForm.fontChkBx.checked );
  });
```

```css
:root {
  --font: cursive, sans-serif;
}

* {
  font-family: var(--font)
}
```

```html
<form id="accesibleForm">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fontChkBx" checked>
    Use custom font
  </label>
</form>

<p>Example Text</p>
```